# ORA-12547 when connect oracle instance in Virtualbox machine using NAT network

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a virtual box machine with server 2008 where Orcale 11g 64 bit is installed, and I can login using sqlplus in the vm.

The vm use the NAT networking and the ip of the vm is '10.0.2.15' (My host ip is 192.168.2.10).

Then I open the Network port forwarding to forward port `1521` in my host to `1521` in the vm .

Then I test the forwarding in my host:

```
telnet localhost 1521
```

It is successful.

However when I treid to create a local net serivce through the `Net Configuration Assistant`, but I meet the error:

```
ORA-12547: TNS lost contact.
```

What's going on?

listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\app\Administrator
```

tnsnames.ora

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what happened, but after I change the `localhost` to `machinename` in the `listener.ora`, it works.

For guys who meet the same problem, you can have a try.